# Elegant way to move templated method definitions out of header file

Tags: c++, templates

In one of my C++ projects, I make use of a many templates. Since I cannot put them in *.cpp files, they whole functions live in the headers at the moment.

But that messes up header files on the one hand, and leads to long compile times on the other hand. How can I handle implementations of templated functions in a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a requirement that templates have to be in the header. They can very well be in a translation unit. The only requirement is that compiler is either able to instantiate them implicitly when they are used or that they get explicitly instantiated.

Whether separating the templatized code into headers and non-headers based on that is feasible depends pretty much on what is being done. It works rather well, e.g., for the IOStreams library because it is, in practice, only instantiated for the character types `char` and `wchar_t`. Writing the explicit instantiations is fairly straight forward and even if there are couple of more character types, e.g., `char16_t` and `char32_t`, it stays feasible. On the other hand, separating templates like `std::vector<T>` in a similar way is rather infeasible.

Using general templates like `std::vector<T>` in interfaces between subsystems quickly starts to become a major problem: while concrete instantiations or selected instantiations are OK, as the subsystem can be implemented without being a template, using arbitrary instantiations would force an entire system to be all templates. Doing so is infeasible in any real-world application which are often a couple of million lines of code on the small end.

What this amounts to is to use compilation-firewalls which are fully typed and don't use arbitrary templates between subsystems. To ease the use of the subsystem interfaces there may be thin template wrappers which, e.g., convert one container type into another container or which type-erase the template parameter where feasible. It needs to be recognized, however, that the compilation separation generally comes at a run-time performance cost: calling a `virtual` function is a lot more expensive than calling an `inline` function. Thus, the abstractions between subsystems may be very different from those within subsystems. For example, iterators are great internal abstractions. Between subsystems, a specific container, e.g., a `std::vector<X>` for some type `X`, tends to be more effective.

Note that the build-time interactions of templates are inherent in their dependency on specific instantiations. That is, even if there is a rather different system for declarations and template definitions, e.g., in the form of a *module* system rather than using header files, it won't become feasible to make everything a template. Using templates for local flexibility works great but they don't work without fixing the instantiations globally in large projects.

Finally a plug: [here](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/22/source-organization-of-templates/) is a write-up on how to organize sources implementing templates.

Comment: Thank you. Currently, compile times became an issue for me, so is there a way to not compile everything when a templated function is modified (at non template specific places).

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a new header file `library_detail.hpp` and include it in your original header.

I've seen some people naming this implementation-header file using `.t` or `.template` extensions as well.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can help is to factor out functionality that doesn't depend on the template arguments into non templated helper functions that can be defined in an implementation file.

As an example, if you were implementing your own vector class you could factor out most of the memory management into a non template class that just works with an untyped array of bytes and have the definitions of its member functions in a .cpp file. The functions that actually need to know the type of the elements are implemented in the templated class in a header and delegate much of the work to the non-templated helpers.